# Why does `eslint` require babel to support class arrow function?

Tags: node.js, eslint

I have defined an arrow function on my `node 12.6.0` application. But when running `eslint` it reports an error about `Parsing error: Unexpected token =`. It works if I add `"parser": "babel-eslint"` on eslint configuration file. I wonder why `eslint` require `babel` for that. This syntax is already supported by `node 12.6.0`.

Below is my eslint configuration file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "airbnb-base"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2018
    },
    "rules": {
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: Just a guess - is ESLint configured to only look for ES5 syntax?

Comment: I have put the eslint configuration in the post. I have added es6 on env.